# Meaning of magit status buffer: Head, Merge, Push

Tags: magit

Can someone explain what the top three lines of the magit status buffer mean? Especially `Merge: origin/master Commit message`

```
Head:     master Commit message
Merge:    origin/master Commit message
Push:     origin/master Commit message
```

Using the console my working directory seems clean and everything is pushed/pulled to/from my remote, so why does the `Merge` appear in magit status?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The `Head` line shows information about the `HEAD` commit. It doesn't say `Branch` instead because `HEAD` may be detached.
- The `Merge` line does not indicate that a merge is in progress. It simply shows the upstream branch of the current branch.  The prefix used for that line used to be `Upstream`, but now `Merge` **or** `Rebase` is used, additionally informing you how upstream changes are pulled into the current branch.

(If you want to rebase by default, then you should set `branch.<branch>.rebase` or `pull.rebase` accordingly. You can do that from the branch popup <kbd>b</kbd> or the branch config popup <kbd>b C</kbd>.)

When a merge *is* in progress, then a "progress section" is shown in the status buffer, but that comes further down and lists the commits that are being merged like so:

_

```
Merging np/submodules (3)
368a666 * origin/np/submodules np/submodules Reorganize submodule popup
c2a58fc * magit-submodule-popup: move (i, s) to nested popup
51c0564 * Add new submodule section type
```

- The `Push` line is about the branch that that the current branch is being pushed to. When using a triangular workflow then the "target of push" is usually different from the "upstream". Long-lived branches such as `master` are the exception to that rule, so for those branches a bit of redundant information is being displayed.

To learn more about triangular workflows and the use of the "push-remote" in Magit (and Git), see this [brief introduction](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-Two-Remotes.html) in the Magit manual.

Comment: If Merge: shows the upstream branch of the current branch then what does Push: show?

Comment: @eflanigan00 In case you weren't notified: see expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how to change from REBASE to MERGE using MAGIT?