# MAGIT: meaning of magit status: head, rebase, push (git newbie)

Tags: spacemacs, magit, git

In my magit status I see the following:

```
Head:     master Commit message
Rebase:   origin/master Commit message
Push:     origin/master Commit message
```

I may have done something (pressed some keys) because I remember it being differently (instead of `Rebase` there was `Merge`).

Could anybody explain me what is going on here?

Comment: I can see it comes from [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/lisp/magit-status.el#L619) but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: I don't use `Magit` so cannot help with its configuration, but to understand `git` terminology better, [Git Pro Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is highly advisable for a, as you stated, *git newbie*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of magit status buffer: Head, Merge, Push](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26247/meaning-of-magit-status-buffer-head-merge-push)